# Zabbix - VFS Trigger for one file in every directory

Tags: centos, monitoring, zabbix

I have same file in every directory with different names.
Like this:

```
/opt/application/directory1/app.jar
/opt/application/directory2/app.jar
/opt/application/directory3/app.jar
/opt/application/directory4/app.jar
/opt/application/directory5/app.jar
/opt/application/directory6/app.jar
```

And I want to check md5sum with zabbix (vfs.md5sum) on every file.
I tried this, but doesnt work:

```
vfs.file.md5sum[/opt/application/*/app.jar]
```

It is possible to check every file with one trigger or I have to create one trigger for one file?

(English is not my mother tongue; please excuse any errors on my part.)

Comment: 'vfs.file.md5sum[file]'
'MD5 checksum of file. Returns character string (MD5 hash of the file)' The implementation of this function (from the source code) suggests that the parameter is a file and not a blob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need individual item and trigger for each file, unless you script the logic outside of Zabbix and only send the result. Individual items and triggers might make it easier to identify the changed file.

To create these automatically, consider using [low level discovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery) (LLD).

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot the LLD. I'm grateful, thank you!